# Beautiful Soup find td by id why isn't this working

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the the Real Estimate price i.e. the 187.40

https://www.marketscreener.com/MICROSOFT-CORPORATION-4835/?type_recherche=rapide&mots=MSFT

It has the following html `td#zbjsfv_dr`

So I have done the following using Beautiful Soup

```
Comp = soup.find("td", id="zbjsfv_dr")
print(Comp)
```

But this isn't returning anything. I don't understand why?

Comment: Can you share all code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong about your bs4 connection because I can get value in `td` which `id=zbjsfv_dr` . You didn't share all code so This is just example:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.marketscreener.com/MICROSOFT-CORPORATION-4835/?type_recherche=rapide&mots=MSFT')
source = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html')

comp = source.find("td", id="zbjsfv_dr")

print(comp.text)
```

OUTPUT:

> 188.085